# How to give a modelsbuilder model to surface controller

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am working on Umbraco 7 with models builder (with custom tool approach). I need to know what is the correct way to pass the model to controller.

For example, I have different kind of pages that derived from my base page and I have a component that I want to generate for all of them, i.e: a big box, with image, text, background, etc.

I thought of it as a partial on my pages. so I wrote an action for it and call it on my pages with the IPageBase as the input parameter. But apparently I cannot do that, specially that models builder doesn't generate a parameterless constructor for me, and it will be ugly if I add a partial class for each of my pages :|

What shall I do? I just don't like to convert my model to view model in my view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to convert huge objects into smaller viewmodels and just pass them into partials, but if you want to have the page model on your partial, you can pass it like this:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage<YourModelClass>
```

or:

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<YourModelClass>
```

and then your controller needs to pass **IPublishedContent** item (*CurrentPage*) as a model to enable conversion to desired class.

You can also do this on the partial / view itself (especially if you want to e.g. use composition object from whole page model). Your partial may looks like:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var seo = new SEO(Model.Content);
    if (seo != null)
    {
        <title>@seo.MetaTitle</title>
        <meta name="description" content="@seo.MetaDescription">
        <meta name="keywords" content="@seo.MetaKeywords">
    }
}
```

where SEO is a class of one of the composition document types / models. Of course, you're able to perform this cast / creation also inside the controller or even service. Hope that it help you to start playing with this further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I like to convert huge objects to smaller ones, but not on my view. How do you do that?

Comment: In the SurfaceController you've got UmbracoContext and UmbracoHelper injected, so you're able to use them to get current page details and construct your viewmodel class (new YourModelClass(CurrentPage)). You can also use some mappers (e.g. AutoMapper) to map page models into corresponding viewmodels (using naming conventions).

Comment: Thanks for the good solution, I really liked it. I also like to know what would you do if you are coming from a macro instead.

Comment: There is more than one possible scenario. You can pass page ID as a parameter and then use UmbracoHelper to do something with it or do it in the same way as on PartialView / View as there is also an option to use Umbraco helper directly there.